# Purpose of am restart?

Tags: crashes

What is the purpose of `am restart`? I can tell it does a quick-reboot(no manufacturer logo, immediate boot animation and quicker reboot)

General curiosity, really. That and logcat suggests that something is using this code when the system wedges and/or crashes.

Comment: From your description I'd conclude it does a "GUI restart" (i.e. just kill the system server which then restarts), which sometimes is also called "quick boot". Pretty useful if you e.g. just installed a new XPosed module and don't want to wait for a full boot :)

Comment: @Izzy True, but this code is triggered fairly randomly. Hell, it can sometimes trigger from just tapping the screen. Any idea why?

Comment: That doesn't sound normal (unless when "just tapping the screen" you usually hit a button labeled "restart"). What kind of ROM do you have? Any other clues you could provide? Maybe link a pastebin with some logcat at least?

Comment: @Izzy Just Android-Andi's SlimRom for the Samsung galaxy tab 2 GTP-3110. Runs at 5.1.1 with a custom kernel and TWRP to boot. There has been a few reported bugs, but little on my scale. The version I'm using is the most stable form available - other than the random restarts, and how negative colours are not yet implemented, its really reliable. I'll grab a logcat when I can, but the restarting is fairly random.

Comment: OK, no clue with that (but welcome to the 5.1.1 trouble with custom ROM – fighting something similar with my P880 having random freezes due to OOM not being able getting some apps adjusted which run with oom_score_adj = -1000 aka "unkillable" – strange stuff, should have stayed with Kitkat ;) Still, a pastebin'd logcat might help.

Comment: @Izzy Glad to know I'm not the only one lol. I'll try and grab logcat as and when I can, though it may be a little while.

Comment: @Izzy Can't get it all on pastebin -something about the buggy mess of copying. Dropboxed the file instead https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lcwkd9lyby1x12/Log.txt?dl=0

Comment: At a quick glance: Bunch of NullPointerExceptions in "core services", all services suddenly die, and finally (as expected) the system server starts over: "Exit zygote because system server (465) has terminated". Looks like a bug in the ROM to me. Connection to your touch-event: "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 22039 (RenderThread)" & "Encountered EGL error 12299 EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW during rendering". Hm, might well be some misbehaving system-app behind it, not sure. Maybe someone more experienced might read more there.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for spotting that. I'll do some digging in the morning, perhaps get in contact with SlimRoms.

Comment: @Izzy Hmmph. I am a tad clueless